# Protractor : Check pdf document in a new tab

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am trying to automate a scenario where I click on a button and its opens up a pdf document in new tab. When the test fails, a json object is displayed instead of the pdf document.

I use this code :

```
            element(by.id('MyButton')).click().then(function () {
            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
                browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {
                    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
                    // Waits for the element is not present on the dom.
                    browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf($('#formattedJson')), 5000);
                });
            });
        });
```

I can open the new tab but when I dont know how to check the content (pdf or json object).
Some advices would be appreciated.

For instance I have the error :

```
Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

Thanks in advance.
;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the window that is rendering your pdf isn't an angular page. You can tell protractor not to wait for angular by using `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`. You should do this right before your call to switch window. Just remember to turn it back on when you close the window and switch back to your main app window. Check out this [documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts#how-to-disable-waiting-for-angular) for more info.

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
    newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); //add this and it should work
    browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        // Waits for the element is not present on the dom.
        browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf($('#formattedJson')), 5000);
    });
}):
```

Comment: Thank you very much tehbeardedone ! You unlocked the situation.